# Google Maps -- Set default location so you don't have to type in City, State for every routing request

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Google Maps, I have a lat-lon for the first point and a street name for the second point.

How can I get Google Maps to search for the street name in the same city as the latlon?

Also, specifying 1234 Some Street, City, State should work as well as 1234 Some Street

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse geocode the lat/long and then use the city, state from the result as the city, state in conjunction with your street address. Here's [a sample showing reverse geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/geocoding-reverse.html).

Comment: Is it possible to do this without manually checking if the destination address has a city / state specified?